# Is raw type of ClassName equivalent to ClassName<Object>?

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

The title is pretty self-explanatory.
Will the raw type of, for example, `ArrayList` act the same as `ArrayList<Object>`?

Comment: Define "act the same".  Do you mean run-time? Then read about [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: Generics is a compile time feature. At runtime it makes little difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. Take a look at

```
  MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass<Integer>();
//MyClass<Object> myClass2 = new MyClass<Integer>();//compilation error
  MyClass<?> myClass3 = new MyClass<Integer>();//this time it compiles

  myClass1.setter(1);
//myClass3.setter(1);//compilation error
```

In case of `myClass2` it will not compile because you are declaring reference to holder of `Objects` but you are passing holder of `Integers` and [generics are not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/1393766)

Also if you change `<Object>` to `<?>` wildcard like in case of `myClass3` you wouldn't be able to use its setter with any object (beside null) like `myClass3.someSetter(1)` because `MyClass<?>` can be reference to `MyClass<Anything>` that can hold any type of objects, and passing `1` to holder of `Strings` would not be safe.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of method signatures, the erased `E` is its bound `Object`, so it is ok to say that the raw `ArrayList` has member methods similar to `ArrayList<Object>`

In terms of subtyping, raw type is more like wildcard type; `ArrayList` is a super type of `ArrayList<x>` for any `x`. On the other hand, `ArrayList<x>` can be converted to raw `ArrayList` without raising any compiler error/warning.

This is all for backward compatibility. You should avoid raw types anyway so you don't need to know these useless information.